# How to set lightning input value using index in aura iteration when button is pressed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-iteration

I want to set the incremented value to lightning input when a button is pressed.
In aura iteration n number of record when I click on a button it is copying the value to all lightning input. But in my case, I would like to set value only to the current input.
I am getting the index but I am not able to set the value.

component :

```
<aura:component >    
    <aura:attribute name="quantity" type="String" default="0"/>
    <aura:attribute name="itemList" type="List" default="[1,2,3]"/>    
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.itemList}" var="prod" indexVar="index">
        <div data-index="{!index}" style="display:flex">
            <lightning:input value="{!v.quantity}" name="{!'itemQuantity_'+ index}" aura:id="itemInput"/>
            <lightning:button label="Add" onclick="{!c.addValue}" name="{!'itemQuantity_'+ index}"/>
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Controller :

```
addValue : function(component, event, helper) {
  var selindex = event.target.dataset.index;
  var count = component.get("v.quantity");        
  count++;
  component.set("v.quantity", count);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've set all the inputs to the same variable, so any change to one will affect them all. Imagine you wrote the following code:

```
let x = 5;
x = 10;
```

What is the value of x? Obviously, it's 10. To fix this, you need a list of values; which is what the iterator already has:

```
<lightning:input value="{!prod}" name="{!'itemQuantity_'+ index}" aura:id="itemInput"/>
```

Which you then set by modifying the list:

```
addValue: function(component, event, helper) {
  let itemList = component.get("v.itemList");
  let index = event.target.dataset.index;
  itemList[index]++;
  component.set("v.itemList", itemList);
}
```